# error in MySQL function

Tags: mysql

Can you tell me what is incorrect with my mysql function?

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION avgRating( ide int(11), ident bool ) RETURNS float
BEGIN
IF ident!=1 THEN

RETURN (
SELECT SUM(RatingVal)/Count(*) 
FROM ratings WHERE id=ide
GROUP BY id
);
ELSE RETURN (
SELECT SUM(RatingVal)/Count(*) 
FROM ratings WHERE id=ide
GROUP BY id);
END IF;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Error from phpMyAdmin after I import the file:

```
        Error
There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 104
STR: //
SQL: DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `avgRating`;# MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).

DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `avgRating`( ide int(11), ident bool ) RETURNS float
BEGIN
    IF ident!=1 THEN

    RETURN (
    SELECT SUM(RatingVal)/Count(*) 
    FROM ratings WHERE id=ide
    GROUP BY id
    );
    ELSE RETURN (
    SELECT SUM(RatingVal)/Count(*) 
    FROM ratings WHERE id=ide
    GROUP BY id);
    END IF;
END //

DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `avgRating`( ide int(11), ident bool ) RETURNS float
BEGIN
    IF ident!=1 THEN

    RETURN (
    SELECT SUM(RatingVal)/Count(*) 
    FROM ratings WHERE id=ide
    GROUP BY id
    );
    ELSE RETURN (
    SELECT SUM(RatingVal)/Count(*) 
    FROM ratings WHERE id=ide
    GROUP BY id);
    END IF;
END //


SQL query: 

DELIMITER // CREATE FUNCTION `avgRating`( ide int(11), ident bool ) RETURNS float BEGIN IF ident!=1 THEN RETURN ( SELECT SUM(RatingVal)/Count(*) FROM ratings WHERE id=ide GROUP BY id ); ELSE RETURN ( SELECT SUM(RatingVal)/Count(*) FROM ratings WHERE id=ide GROUP BY id); END IF; END //

MySQL said: 

#1418 - This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)
```

Comment: what for is your bool parameter?

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: This post is a mess - is your function defined 3 times?

Comment: Just a note (not your error), but the statements after THEN and ELSE is identical in your function, so `IF A THEN B ELSE B END`.